# How to check if google/gmail account is real?

Tags: c#, authentication, google-api, google-account

I am writing a small application that lets the user get a spreadsheet from his Google docs.
I am making a log-in Form that requests a email address and name, and then tries to connect to Google, and to check if the account that was entered is real.

I'm using the spreadsheet API, and there is a class called `SpreadsheetsService` but it doesn't have any status property; it just throws an exception when I enter a wrong account name.

My questions:
Is there a library that returns a Status code for this situation?

Should I check the class  `SpreadsheetsService` and check if an exception was thrown? (I have to use a function from this class to produce this)

Comment: Google won't tell you if it's real or not.  You just have to send it and hope it is.  Think about the spamming repercussions if they did verify email addresses.

Comment: yeah that make sense, so should i just check if i get any spreadsheet return to me when i call it? (this is only way to check if an execption was thrown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool isValid()
{
    try
    {
       connect();
    }
    catch
    {
       return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```